# How to remove a JSON objectForKey which is different throughout the NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

I have following response of filtered array 2

```
    if(requestType == RequestTypeGetReportMaterialStatus)
            {
                materialStatusArray=response[@"customerstatus"];
                NSLog(@"Filtered Array2%@",materialStatusArray);
}

1 =     {
    bookingid = 469;
    status = 1;
};
2 =     {
    bookingid = 493;
    status = 1;
};
3 =     {
    bookingid = 486;
    status = 1;
};
4 =     {
    bookingid = 501;
    status = 1;
};
5 =     {
    bookingid = 506;
    status = 1;
};
```

But I want to a response to stored in a array which gives the following out put by cutting the numbers

```
   {

    bookingid = 469;

    status = 1;

};

   {

    bookingid = 493;

    status = 1;

};

   {

    bookingid = 486;

    status = 1;

};

     {

    bookingid = 501;

    status = 1;

};

    {

    bookingid = 506;

    status = 1;

};
```

How can I get the above format of array response to access the bookingid and status values for a comparision purpose... Please help me out by giving code snippet according to my response.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `materialStatusArray` is a NSDictionary actually, the array could be converted like:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayWithoutNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];

if ([materialStatusArray isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)materialStatusArray;
    [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [arrayWithoutNumbers addObject:obj];
    }]
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution, Thanks!.